# FaunaDB: Selecting all ID from a collection of documents

Tags: node.js, graphql, nosql, faunadb

I need to list all id of documents in collection. I was following this:

https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/start/fql_for_sql_users.html?lang=javascript

In Sql what I want to do would be:
SELECT id from Person

but in the example here, it will return all “columns” of Person. (SELECT * from Person)

How can I make an index that specify only id from the collections?

Comment: With id, you mean the document reference? Luigi

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Index with values = id.

For e.g.

```
{
  "shipperID" : 1,
  "companyName" : "Speedy Express",
  "phone" : "(503) 555-9831"
}
```

```
CreateIndex(
{
name: "shippers_id",
source: Collection("shippers"),
values:  [{field: ["data", "shipperID"]}]
})
```

`SELECT shipperID FROM shippers` in fql would be `Paginate(Match(Index("shippers_id")))`